# Calculating cross section of rectangle by angle

Tags: geometry

Given this:

[image: Random image]

How do you calculate the length of the green line, given x degrees, and the fact that height / width = 2 / 5?

The blue line indicates at 0 degrees.

The length of the pink line equals exactly 1, which is maximum.

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the pink line is 1 and the height/width is 2/5, then the height of the rectangle is $\frac 2{\sqrt{29}}$ and the width is $\frac 5{\sqrt{29}}$.

Look at the triangle formed by the lower half of the green line, the lower half of the blue line, and the bottom edge of the rectangle.  $\cos x = $ half of the height of the rectangle / half of the length of the green line.  So the length of the green line is the height of the rectangle divided by $\cos x$.

Comment: @Yes, but what if x is greater than the pink angle?

Comment: Draw a horizontal blue line, form a triangle, and write a relationship for $\cos (90-x)$.

Comment: The question did not say where the blue line is located (but it should). Then, we have to assume that it is right at the middle. It would be more interesting if it is k (known) units from the right edge?

Comment: @Mick Yes it is exactly in the center, always

Comment: I will make a gif to make it much clearer